# Backticks vs. $() in strings/variable assignment

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-syntastic

I'm *quite* new to Vimscript and editing `~/.vimrc`, and was tweaking this file after having installed Pathogen and Syntastic to do live syntax checking for JavaScript. However, in my current set-up, I want Syntastic to use the per-project executables for the syntax checking, located within `./node_modules/.bin/` (the command `npm bin` returns this path). In my search for how to do this, I came across GitHub issues like [this](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/1692), using the following Vimscript variable and assignment (or something like it; there are several instances on that page):

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exe = '$(npm bin)/eslint'
```

However, in my attempts to use this construct, it wouldn't "work"; `eslint` isn't found, and running `:SyntasticInfo` shows that there are no checkers available for `.js` and `.jsx` files. However, when I adapted this to the following...

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exec = '`npm bin`/eslint'
```

... it works! Could someone explain to me, this noob, why the first construct doesn't work, what I could be missing here? Really wanting to learn!

Comment: The first form doesn't work because you're taking it out of context: syntastic needs an `exec` (not `exe`) pointing to a valid `eslint` executable.  The second form works only as long as you don't switch to a different project from within Vim.  See the thread you quoted for possible solutions.  Or use `autocmd`s.  Or use something like [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) instead of syntastic.  Either way, syntastic is not the best way to start learning about Vim.

Comment: @lcd047 Thanks so much for this! Yeah, I saw that, but the distinction of `_exe` and `_exec` was a bit obtuse to me... and the suggestion of adding the path to _any_ binary as the `_exec` setting didn't make much sense, nor did it work, as vim complained like so: `syntastic: error: checker javascript/eslint: can't parse version string (abnormal termination?)`

Comment: @lcd047 However, I most thank you about your suggestion of ALE! This is great; gonna set it up in an hr. or two! Thanks so much!